# Centralize child form does not work

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have an application that works as follows: There is a main form which are open child forms for registration, search, etc. The intention is always open child forms in the center of the main form, regardless of the size of it. For this I am using the following code in the form son onCreate:

```
formChild->Left=(MainForm->pnlMain->Width/2);
formChild->Top=(MainForm->pnlMain->Height/2)-(formChild->Height/2);
```

So far everything right, the form is centered correctly, as shown in the following image:

[image]

When the child form is closed, the main form is restored and the son form is opened, the following problem occurs:
[image]

The child form is generated in the position that was generated the first time (with the maximized window).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are you constructing the child form each time the app wants to display it or is the same instance being used over and over? Try putting your code into an OnShow event handler of the child form.

Comment: I already tried with OnShow event. The behavior is same.

Comment: You are not using the width and height of the form. You are using these properties of a panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to deal with this is to set the Child Form's `Position` property to `poMainFormCenter`.

This will make sure that when the child form is created and shown for the first time, it will be centered on the MainForm.

NOTE, the Child Form's position won't be updated if you simply hide it and then show it again later.  If you need the Child Form to always be centered each time it is shown, you should destroy it when it is closed and then re-create it before showing it.

Comment: I'm using delete form in onClose event of my form child, but the Violation Access error it is shown. Which is the correct way for delete form in runtime?